# ajax with beforeSend but credentials hidden

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I have this ajax calls:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: beforeSend,
        url: someUrl
```

For `beforeSend` I got:

```
const beforeSend = function ( xhr ) { xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( UserPass ) );};
```

With:

```
const Base64 = {_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}};

const UserPass = 'SomeLogin:SomePass'
```

But this is not ok, I can't have the credentials 'SomeLogin:SomePass' there in my javascript. How can I hide them or use them from PHP or something? I'm calling this ajax directly from a html page, I'm using Symfony. Some guy told me "Read it from a cookie" but I didn't get it how, which cookie.

Comment: An attempt of solution is to use JWT (json web token) through this bundle LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle where you can combine with symfony guard. With this, for each user, your app can authenticate once and send you a credential token that you can store in local storage and use it (for example in Authorization http header) to perform each request to secure resource. It's just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are files stored at the end of the client (in this case it is stored by the browser) and they contain important informations for the user about the website. Hopefully a session id is inside the cookie. A session id is a value which identifies a session. A session is a concept which denotes the usage of a service (in this case the website) via a channel (in this case the browser).

You can get the cookie of a page via `document.cookie` (javascript code). Run

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

and you will see the value of your cookie for the given site in the browser console. A cookie can contain multiple values, so there are several libraries which aim to simplify your interactions with cookies.

EDIT:

The idea is to use a session id, because in that case even if your session id is stolen, your username and password will still remain only in your possession.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep the credentials secret, not visibile by the browser you should not keep them in the browser. You could use your server as a proxy. Make an ajax call to your server and have the server make the authed called to the service.

On the other hand if the credentials are specific to each user, you can use them as such, just make sure you are making HTTPS calls so nobody can see the request’s body.

Comment: I was trying this "It is possible for your app to authenticate once and set a session cookie, then create handler on the resource folders to check for that authentication cookie." But thanks, you are right. I will call some PHP routes from the ajax and use the credentials through PHP (I already did this, but didn't want to change the whole code in my javascript), I don't know how to do what you saying, thanks.